# Wait all byte (JSSC)

Tags: java, serial-communication, jssc

I'm trying to read a String from my Sara g350 module. I'm using a serial port comunication. The code that I use is this one:

```
private static SerialPort serialPort;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] portNames = SerialPortList.getPortNames();

    if (portNames.length == 0) {
        System.out.println("There are no serial-ports :( You can use an emulator, such ad VSPE, to create a virtual serial port.");
        System.out.println("Press Enter to exit...");
        try {
            System.in.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return;
    }

    // OPEN PORT
    System.out.println("Available com-ports:");
    for (int i = 0; i < portNames.length; i++){
        System.out.println(portNames[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("Type port name, which you want to use, and press Enter...");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String portName = in.next();

    // writing to port
    serialPort = new SerialPort(portName);
    try {
        // opening port
        serialPort.openPort();

        serialPort.setParams(SerialPort.BAUDRATE_9600,
                             SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
                             SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                             SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

        serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN | 
                                      SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_OUT);

        serialPort.addEventListener(new PortReader(), SerialPort.MASK_RXCHAR);
        // writing string to port
        serialPort.writeString("AT+CMEE=2");

        System.out.println("String wrote to port, waiting for response..");
    }
    catch (SerialPortException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in writing data to port: " + ex);
    }
}

// receiving response from port
private static class PortReader implements SerialPortEventListener {

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
        if(event.isRXCHAR() && event.getEventValue() > 0) {
            try {
                // получение ответа от порта
                String receivedData = serialPort.readString(event.getEventValue());
                System.out.println("Received response from port: " + receivedData);
            }
            catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                System.out.println("Error in receiving response from port: " + ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The Problem is that i read only the eco response and not all String.
I send "AT+CMEE=2" and the response could be:
AT+CMEE=2

OK

Can anyone help me? Thank you!